# What is the purpose of the UserManager class in django?

Tags: python, django, class

What is the purpose of the UserManager class in django?

The documentation doesn't seem to really explain what it is for.

Comment: The main purpose is to create (super)users. Since passwords are hashed, that is not simply achivable with a `.create(..)`.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose is to create (super)users. Since passwords are hashed, that is not simply achivable with a [**`.create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create).

The [**`UserManager`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager) is thus a `Manager`, with extra methods:

- [**`.create_user(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) to create a user;
- [**`.create_superuser(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_superuser) to create a user that is a superuser; and
- [**`with_perm(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.with_perm) that returns a set of `User` objects that have a given permission.

If we take a look at the standard [`UserManager` implementation [GitHUb]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L130-L146), we see:

> ```
>     def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
>         """
>         Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
>         """
>         if not username:
>             raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
>         email = self.normalize_email(email)
>         username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
>         user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
>         user.set_password(password)
>         user.save(using=self._db)
>         return user
>
>     def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
>         extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
>         extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
>         return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
> ```

It will thus normalize both the username and email address, and furthermore use the [**`.set_password(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) to set the password, to ensure that the password is *hashed* before saving it to the database.